# how to add Add Training Phrases in Dialog Flow through PYTHON SDK

Tags: dialogflow-es

"How can I use the Python SDK for Dialogflow ES to add training phrases and associate them with existing entities? I can add the training phrases, but they don't seem to be tagged to the existing entities. What am I missing?"

can you help me with the process to tag texts in training phrases to existing entities